# What is the right way to use Firebase Database ChildEventListener with ViewModel?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, android-lifecycle, android-viewmodel

In Android OS, due to various configuration changes, such as orientation change, the activity gets destroyed and recreated. But this also in results more cost - such as refetching of the data to display the UI. Therefore, `ViewModel` was developed for keeping data present until the activity is really destroyed - keeping it safe during configuration changes.

I have been using Firebase Realtime Database in my application and I am very well known with `ChildEventListener` present in Firebase SDKs. Since there are so many advantages of using `ViewModel` - I am interested to use it within my app. I have read various sources, blogs regarding `ViewModel` architecture along with Firebase: but they use ValueEvent Listeners only. I am displaying `RecyclerView` within the app and `ChildEventListener` is a perfect candidate for this.

I want to maintain a list using `ChildEventListener` with `ViewModel` architecture. I have written code to actively fetch data using `ViewModel`.

```
class DataViewModel : ViewModel() {

    private var listenerRemovePending = false
    private val listener = MyChildEventListener()
    private val handler = Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())
    private lateinit var dataListRef: DatabaseReference

    var data: MutableLiveData<ArrayList<DataModel>> = MutableLiveData()
    val dataList: ArrayList<DataModel> = arrayListOf()

    fun getData(userId: String): LiveData<ArrayList<DataModel>> {
        dataListRef =
            FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("/data/$userId/data")
        dataListRef.addChildEventListener(object : ChildEventListener {
            override fun onCancelled(databaseError: DatabaseError) {
                Log.e(
                    LOG_TAG,
                    "Can't listen to query :dataListRef",
                    databaseError.toException()
                )
            }

            override fun onChildMoved(snapshot: DataSnapshot, previousChildName: String?) {
                TODO("Not yet implemented")
            }

            override fun onChildChanged(snapshot: DataSnapshot, previousChildName: String?) {
                TODO("Not yet implemented")
            }

            override fun onChildAdded(snapshot: DataSnapshot, previousChildName: String?) {
                if (snapshot.exists()) {
                    val item: DataModel? =
                        snapshot.getValue(DataModel::class.java)
                    if (item != null) {
                        dataList.add(item)
                    }
                    data.value = dataList
                }
            }

            override fun onChildRemoved(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                TODO("Not yet implemented")
            }
        })
        return data
    }

    companion object {
        private const val LOG_TAG = "DataViewModel"
    }
}
```

I am satisfied with its result. But here is a major problem - I want this `ChildEventListener` to be detached if there is no observer (Activity is not active). Currently, this listener is active, till the activity ends - This `ViewModel` will keep its listener attached until Activity's `onDestroy` method is called.

So my question is how can I can do from here to detach listener on the inactive state?

Answer (score 0):

You should override onCleared() function inside your ViewModel class. But if you wnat to use MVVM patterns, your network request should be inside SomRequestRemoteDataSource.

```
override fun onCleared() {
    super.onCleared()
    dataListRef.removeEventListener(yourChildListener)
}
```